# Why doesn't FileMerge show full file?

Tags: software, macos, file

I am trying to compare & merge two text files in FileMerge (using it for the first time). The thing is that the files contents are not shown in full. The contents of the files being compared are clipped. Why is this happening?

Comment: can you say exactly what you mean, that the files are not shown in full. i.e. "there are lines at the end of file A/file B/both that are not shown", or "you don't see the full width of the documents".  Better still, if a screenshot shows the issue, upload or link a screenshot from imgur.

Comment: @StuWilson - there are lines at the end of files A & B which are not shown. There are about 1300+ lines in both A & B files, but the comparison is shown only till 1100 lines.